# Anaconda Working Environment "not available" in navigator, but still in use when I launch JupyterLab from OS terminal

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, environment-variables, jupyter-lab

I opened Anaconda Navigator earlier and a pop-up appeared saying "WorkingEnv no longer available". `WorkingEnv` is my working environment for JupyterLab outside of the `base` environment directory.

I launched jupyter lab from my OS terminal, and it looks like it is still using the same kernel associated with my `WorkingEnv` despite it not being in the anaconda navigator.

[image: Screenshot of kernel here]

I have checked in Finder to see if the `WorkingEnv` still exists, which it does. But when I run `conda envs list1` I am only returned with the base environment.

```
# conda environments:
#base                  *  /Users/noraanzawi/anaconda3
```

Compared to what is in the Finder folder

[image: see screenshot here]

Why is this?